# Software for computing n-Clique, n-Clan, n-Plex?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science

I am studying graph theory and complex network into details, I would like to ask if some one could help providing a useful (academic) tools or some good tools for computing n-clique, n-clan, n-core, etc,,
Or even some tools for finding centrality, density, closeness, betweeness, e-eccentricity.... or some thing like these measurements ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For a start you should take a look at [Sagemath](http://www.sagemath.org/). Simple example to get you started

```
sage: G = graphs.RandomGNP(10,0.6)
sage: G.centrality_betweenness()
{0: 0.03935185185185185,
 1: 0.0,
 2: 0.0,
 3: 0.034722222222222224,
 4: 0.27083333333333326,
 5: 0.24537037037037038,
 6: 0.011574074074074072,
 7: 0.04629629629629629,
 8: 0.04629629629629629,
 9: 0.0}
sage: G.clique_maximum()
[0, 4, 5, 7]
```